# How to make multiple scroll in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: Example this 4 scroll]

How to make 4 scroll in flutter?

Comment: You might be looking for [DataTable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple scrolls in a Row widget like:

```dart
Row(
 children: [
    Flexible(
      flex: 1,
      child : SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).height,
        child: SingleChildScrollView()
      )
    ),
    Flexible(
      flex: 5,
      child : SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).height,
        child: SingleChildScrollView()
      )
    ),
    Flexible(
      flex: 1,
      child : SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).height,
        child: SingleChildScrollView()
      )
    ),
    Flexible(
      flex: 1,
      child : SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).height,
        child: SingleChildScrollView()
      )
    )
 ]
)
```